# How to add Text if there is no Image and no Link showed (PHP)?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Im using this code to show Image with link and show Image if there is no link. But i need to show something else if client doesnt put any Link and Image at all. So if there is no Image and Link, show anything else. (example text: No content):

```
<div class="link__inner">
     <?php 
     $link = get_field('link_product');
     if( $link ): 
     $link_url = $link['url'];
     ?> 

     <a class="button" target="_blank" href="<?php echo esc_url( $link_url ); ?>">
       <img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url();?>" alt="">
     </a>

     <?php else: ?>

     <img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url();?>" alt="">

     <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

[IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLo8N.png)

Comment: Just store the link in a variable and check both `if (!$link && !$image)`? Btw, `the_post_thumbnail_url()` will already output the link for you instead or returning it, so no echo needed. To get the URL without it automatically being outputted (so you can store it in a variable), use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` instead. In WP, it there are functions named `the_*`, it outputs the value when you call it, and `get_the_*` will return the value without outputting it.

Comment: im not very good with Php, so it would be perfect if you can send me code of this what you saying please!

Comment: You can read the manuals: [Here's WP's manual about get_the_post_thumbnail_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) and [here is PHP's manual about if](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) and [else](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php) and [elseif](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php). Here's also [PHP's manual about comparison operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: Im trying it since 3 hours but im not understanding, anyway thank u